# FreeBSD: /etc/rc.conf persistently read-only

Tags: freebsd, rc

I am running a single-user FreeBSD and I am trying to edit `rc.conf` but it appears to be read-only for some reason. I can't change it from the root account. Indeed, `id` gives:

`uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel),5(operator)`

Trying to mount with `mount -u -w` does not help either.

Comment: Try to read the official BSD, it may be a spcefic issue/feature related to the OS.

Comment: Could you say something about how and why you have entered single-user mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mentioned in the FreeBSD FAQ's [System Administration section](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/faq/#admin).

See especially section 10.5, which is aptly named [I made a mistake in rc.conf, or another startup file, and now I cannot edit it because the file system is read-only. What should I do?](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/faq/#rcconf-readonly).

## 10. System Administration

#### 10.1. Where are the system start-up configuration files?

The primary configuration file is **/etc/defaults/rc.conf** which is described in [rc.conf(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.conf&sektion=5&format=html). System startup scripts such as **/etc/rc** and **/etc/rc.d**, which are described in [rc(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.conf&sektion=5&format=html), include this file. Do not edit this file! Instead, to edit an entry in **/etc/defaults/rc.conf**, copy the line into **/etc/rc.conf** and change it there.

For example, to start [sshd(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8&format=html), the included OpenSSH daemon:

```
# echo 'sshd_enable="YES"' >> /etc/rc.conf
```

Alternatively, use [sysrc(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysrc&sektion=8&format=html) to modify **/etc/rc.conf**:

```
# sysrc sshd_enable="YES"
```

To start up local services, place shell scripts in the **/usr/local/etc/rc.d** directory. These shell scripts should be set executable, the default file mode is 555.

Comment: ```sysrc``` works fine; thanks.

Comment: It's interesting to see that this answer was accepted by the OP, even though it never even touches on the issue of the read-only file system that the user is dealing with.

Comment: @Kusalananda my answer indeed touch the subject and it is the only acceptable answer here if you read carefully BSD

Comment: @SatoshiNakamoto As the information was buried deep in one of the links you provided, I made an edit to ensure a better link pointing directly to the relevant info was shown.  Now I don't know what you want to do with the second half of your answer, which seems irrelevant.

Comment: First of all, don't change my answer! That's against stackoverflow.com rules, you should only change a question/answer to clarify. Second, your relevance is only relevant to you! and again you changed my answer to point yours, give your answer instead. Your quick -judgmental-fast-paced-can't-read-I-am-programmer who couldn't understand the second sentence tells a lot about you as a programmer, if that didn't make sense to you you probably shouldn't carry a computer. The second part continues the instructions of the first.

Answer (score 2):

You can fulfill **mount -a**, which will allow you to mount all FS with attributes from **/etc/fstab**.
If some FS contains errors, you will have to perform **fsck** for this FS and try again **mount -a**.
A ZFS system you may need to run **zfs mount -a**.

Comment: Did that, didn't work. But thanks.

Comment: What type of file system do you have?